# tensorflow saved model to java

Tags: tensorflow, java, classifier

Hello data scientists (I'm not),
I adapted a multi-class-text-classification-cnn from https://github.com/jiegzhan/multi-class-text-classification-cnn (thanks Jie Zhang)
It works ! 90% accuracy !
Now my issue ;-)
I really need to load my model with java in order to allow my existing java service to predict categories.
According to documentations, I need to use SavedModelBuilder which is the new way of modele saving. I tried for hours but I misse a lot of things... About signature, assets. 
If someone could help me with that ? => replace the old saver.save by tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder into https://github.com/jiegzhan/multi-class-text-classification-cnn/blob/master/train.py
He or she will have my infinite gratitude

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_java

Answer (score 1):

#### train.py code:

```
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder("/home/datam/cnn-text-classification-tf/model/20180423")
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
    sess,
    [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
    clear_devices=True
)
builder.save()
```

#### Java Coding:

```
SavedModelBundle model = SavedModelBundle.load(SAVED_MODEL_PATH+"/20180423", "serve");
Session s = model.session();
Graph g = model.graph();
```